# Use of instanceof in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Consider this basic node+ts code:

```
import * as express from "express";

function doStuff(app: express.Application) {
  if (!(app instanceof express.Application)) throw new TypeError();
  // etc...
}
```

VSCode shows me this error for `...instanceof express.Application...`:

> [ts] Property 'Application' does not exist on type 'typeof e'. [2339]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instanceof` is a Javascript operator. The right hand side operand must be a runtime value (a function or a constructor)  for it to work.

`express.Application` is defined as an interface. Interfaces only exist at compile time to aid in type checking. This means at runtime, there is no `express.Application` value to be the operand in the `instanceof` operation, and so typescript issues an error.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I could use duck typing to achieve the same result, though that's messy... is there an alternative?

Comment: @Ionix As the type is defined you can only check if specific properties exist